# size of object keys in javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, object, key, size

I have a simple question about javascript.

Does it matter (as far as performance is concerned) the size of the keys in a javascript object ?

Here are 2 examples :

a. short keys

```
 var obj = {};
 obj['a'] = { x : 1, y : 0 };
 obj['b'] = { x : 1, y : 0 };
 obj['c'] = { x : 1, y : 0 };
```

b. long keys

```
var obj = {};
obj['this_is_a_long_key'] = { x : 1, y : 0 };
obj['this_is_a_longer_key'] = { x : 1, y : 0 };
obj['this_is_the_longest_key'] = { x : 1, y : 0 };
```

So if I am searching/editing very often the properties ( which can be many ) of those objects, does the size of the key have to do anything with the performance of the searching/editing etc actions ?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Large keys aren't *free*, because ultimately the runtime has to perform hash and comparison operations when looking up properties. However, unless you've got a very large number of long keys, it's probably not worth worrying about.

Modern JavaScript environments are generally optimized enough to allow you to concentrate on writing code the way you want, so that (as Joe Armstrong famously says about Erlang) your code is as beautiful as it can be. Concentrate on *algorithmic* efficiency, and worry about details like this if you're really up against a performance barrier.

Comment: I see. I am up against a performance barrier and I am looking my code trying to find ways to achieve a better performance. I have also other things in my code that I can immprove and i was just thinking if the keynames are one of them.
Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: @ThanosKw I would be extremely surprised to learn that long property names are an important part of your performance issues.

Comment: Good, I get it. So I ll leave them as they are, long and nice :)